# every function has an injective extension that respects its order

Tags: functions, axiom-of-choice

I'm told that for every real-valued function $f$ there is an injective function $f'$ that respects the ordering given by $f$ in that $$f(a) < f(b) \implies f'(a) < f'(b)$$ and $$a \neq b \text{ and } f(a) = f(b) \;\; \implies \;\; f'(a) \neq f'(b)$$
Where $<$ is the usual less-than operation.

I'm told that the existence of such an $f'$ has something to do with the axiom of choice. If anyone could shed some light on this..

( The context of this problem is page 18 of https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3378/PRG56.pdf )

Comment: This question has absolutely no context. What is $<$? I don't want to have to go to a different file on a different website. Please add the context to your question.

Comment: More context added ... though one could assume, with relatively little trouble, that < is some form of order relation.

Comment: Sure. Order on what? Now that you've added "real-valued" it makes a lot more sense all of a sudden, for some reason. I left my mind reading glasses in my other pants. So I'm sorry that I couldn't immediately tell what you wanted to ask.

Comment: "Extension" doesn't seem like the right word here (although I see it is used in your linked document), as that word generally means that the domain of $f'$ contains the domain of $f$, and the two functions agree on the domain of $f$. If I am understanding correctly, your $f'$ need not agree with $f$ anywhere. Apologies if I am misreading somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Let $f$ be any real function such that the preimage of each real has at least 2 points. Suppose there is some injective $f'$ for this $f$. For each real $r$, choose $a_r \neq b_r \in f^{-1}[\{r\}]$. Let $x_r$ be a rational between $f'(a_r)$ and $f'(b_r)$. Then $r \neq s$ implies $x_r \neq x_s$ which is impossible.